# Better way to replace characters in a string - Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark-sql, databricks, databricks-sql

I am new to Spark and Databricks Sql. I have the below mentioned query. I am sure there should be a smart way to represent the same expression instead of using 3 `regexp_replace()` functions as given below. In essence, I need to get rid off the `-`, `:`, `' '`. Also, can we get rid of the milliseconds part too ?

```
select 
    regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(MAX(rec_insertdttm), '-', ''), ':', ''), ' ', '') as my_dttm 
from mydb.mytable
```

The output of this query is something like :- `'20230817162231.730846'` and I want : `20230817162231`

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your column is actually a `TIMESTAMP` type, you can use the `date_format` built-in SQL function to efficiently format it:

```sql
select 
  date_format(rec_insertdttm, 'yyyyMMddHHmmss') 
from mydb.mytable;
```

- https://docs.databricks.com/en/sql/language-manual/functions/date_format.html
- https://docs.databricks.com/en/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html

---

If your type is a `STRING`, you can `CAST(rec_insertdttm AS TIMESTAMP)` and pass that to the same `date_format()` solution above.

---

Or you can regex replace multiple characters at once using a [regex character range](https://chortle.ccsu.edu/finiteautomata/Section07/sect07_11.html): `regexp_replace(rec_insertdttm, '[\- :.]', '')`. But the `date_format()` solution is much better for readability and simplicity.

Comment: thank you @Zach. I went with the `date_format()` approach that you suggested.